# how to change the path of vim command

Tags: bash, osx, vim

I have two versions of `vim` installed on macOS:

- a default version, `/usr/bin/vim`,
- and MacVim (via Homebrew), `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

When I type `vim`, the default program is invoked. I want to use MacVim whenever I type `vim`. Do you know how? Do both of them use the same `~/.vimrc` file?

Comment: @Christopher no, it is not , because I actually installed brew install vim, and the output of ls -l is `lrwxr-xr-x  1 name  admin  30 Jun  4 19:12 /usr/local/bin/vim -> ../Cellar/vim/8.1.1450/bin/vim`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use an alias.

The alias is defined in one of your BASH RC files, such as `~/.bashrc`. Below, if `/usr/local/bin/vim` is a symbolic link, then create an alias called `vim`.

```
if [ -h '/usr/local/bin/vim' ]; then
    alias vim='/usr/local/bin/vim'
fi
```

The same logic can be applied as follows.

```
[ -h '/usr/local/bin/vim' ] && alias vim='/usr/local/bin/vim'
```

- `-h` tests if a file is a symbolic link which might be the case when using Homebrew.
- `-x` tests if a file is a regular executable file.

(One can determine that a file is a link when `ls -l` shows the first letter of its permissions as the letter, l, in **l**rwxr-xr-x.)

One might also want to set a couple of variables that programs use to invoke a default editor.

```
EDITOR='/usr/local/bin/vim'
VISUAL='/usr/local/bin/vim'
```

After adding the definition to your shell's RC file, source the RC file to pick up the new alias with `source ~/.bashrc` or whichever file was appropriate for your BASH configuration. The command, `command -v vim`, shows the alias was created when its output is as follows.

```
alias vim=/usr/local/bin/vim
```

The same VIM RC files are used by both versions of `vim`.

The advantage of pointing to the symbolic link instead of the binary executable is that the alias does not need to be updated on each upgrade of MacVim, which is often. Homebrew keeps the symbolic link pointed to the right binary executable when upgrades are performed with `brew update && brew upgrade`, for example.

---

The system version, `/usr/bin/vim`, should stay where it is. Without disabling System Integrity Protection (SIP), it cannot be deleted or altered anyway. It is still possible to use the system version by typing `/usr/bin/vim`, yet, typing `vim` invokes `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

---

### Modify the path.

Another way that would work for all software installed via Homebrew is to modify the `PATH` so that all software installed by Homebrew is first in the `PATH`. To start, one needs to know which `zsh` RC file already contains the definition of the path.

```
cd
grep path .z*
```

One of the results might include `fpath`. This is not the right variable. We're looking for a lower-case variable named `path`. After deducing the name of the file to edit, which is likely either `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile`, change the value of the `path` variable. For example, the `path` below defines `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` first, followed by scripts or programs in the home directory, and lastly the remainder of the path that has already been defined by the system.

```
path=(
    /usr/local/{bin,sbin}
    $HOME/bin
    $path
)
```

The resultant Unix `PATH` variable would then be defined as follows.

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/$username/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The `zsh` `path` and Unix `PATH` variables are "bound together" by `typseset`, so just `source` the file that was edited to modify the `path` variable: `source ~/.zprofile`, for example. Then take a look at the `PATH` variable to learn if it was modified as expected: `echo $PATH`.

---

The Homebrew package maintainers are quite good at recognizing which software would cause a problem with macOS if `/usr/local/bin` is first in the path, before `/usr/bin`. For example, if Homebrew is to install GNU `id`, then the name of the software in `/usr/local/bin` would be `gid` to avoid issues with BSD `id` in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard with brew is to put `/usr/local/bin` on your `PATH` before system directories like `/usr/bin` so that it’s commands get picked up first.